# Using Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions to specify an RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

With Elastic Beanstalk, can you specify whether you want to create an RDS database using .ebextensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, .ebextensions are evaluated per deployment, not per environment creation. You can choose to create or not the RDS when you create the Environmnet automatically the CLI or the API. Also, you can use a `Resources` key with the `AWSEBRDSDatabase` name in you .ebextensions to get a reference to that database.

see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html