# Programmaticaly configuring an RDS instance for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to automate the creation of the temporary environment, I am struggling with the creation of a related RDS instance inside Elastic Beanstalk.

I would like that when I call `eb create envName` the environment also spawns an RDS database.

One solution would be to manually do it. Another solution seems to involve '.ebextensions' [Using Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions to specify an RDS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978501/using-elastic-beanstalk-ebextensions-to-specify-an-rds-database) , though `.ebextensions` are to be run at each deployment, this could fit through a specific hook, but I would like to have my config in `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` because this is the file that seems to have preconfiguration for when I call `eb` commands.

One of the reason to not but it in `.ebextensions` is also that in the project configuration, those are not environment specific, they describe the requirements for the app in any environment.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe it is a bad idea to create the database as part of the environment, as it is a lot harder to deal with stopping and recreating the environment if you need to. I believe it is a lot easier and safer to keep the database running even if you want to completely destroy the environment and start all over. I believe most experience users will recommend you to manage the RDS on your own (outside EB). It is really easy anyway.

That said (and given you didn't ask for that), you can simply create a database as part of the `eb create` command itself:

```
eb create -db -db.engine postgres -db.version 9.4 -db.user dbroot -db.i ...
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html